# Google, Facebook, Yahoo oauth/oauth2 in Android application

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to implement Yahoo oauth and Google, Facebook oauth2 in my Android application.
Whether there are similar libraries for Android like HybridAuth that act as an abstract api between your application and various social apis and identities providers such as Facebook, Yahoo and Google or I need to implement it from scratch ?

One other question - is it a good idea to use Android AccountManager to get OAuth2 access to user account ? Will it work on the "gray" chinese android phones without valid google phone id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find exactly what you are for here: https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/